# How to use a nested array to make a chatbot that can send messages based on your response?

Tags: javascript, arrays, chatbot

I'm trying to make a simple chatbot in JavaScript that can send messages based on the user's input through an input field. How can I make it so the bot moves the conversation to the next array if it recognizes the correct response from the user?

E.g. if you respond with `pizza`, it would continue with `story2`. But if you respond with `salads`, it would pick `story3`.

The conversations should be linear, so you cannot suddenly skip to `story4` if you respond with `medium` while still at `story1`.

```
var story1 = [
  { m: 'Hello!'},
  { m: 'Should I eat pizza or salads?'}, 
  { options: [
    { response: 'pizza', next: story2},
    { response: 'salads', next: story3},
  ]},
];

var story2 = [
  { m: 'Pizza it is!'},
  { m: 'What size pizza do you want?'},
  { options: [
    { response: 'medium', next: story4},
    { response: 'large', next: story5},
  ]},
];

var story3 = [
  { m: 'Salad it is!'},
];

var story4 = [
  { m: 'Ok! Medium pizza!'},
];

var story5 = [
  { m: 'Ok! Large pizza!'},
];
```

Comment: This can be solved in a multitude of ways. First approach that comes to mind is keeping track of the current "story step" in a variable and then listening to the chat input/submit event to trigger an appropriate response based on the entered value.

Answer (score 0):

i think with object will be more easier than arrays... try this

```
    const response = userAnswer;
```

u will retrieve like this : obj[response].m   or what ever you want

```
    const obj = {
    pizza: {
    key: 'story1,'
       m: 'Should I eat pizza or salads?', 
       options: [
         {response: 'pizza', next: story2},
        {response: 'salads', next: story3},
      ],
    },
    salads: {
      key: 'story3',
      m: 'Salad it is!',
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```js
const step = 0

const stories = [
    story1,
    story2,
    story3,
    ...
]

function triggerStepAction(e) {
    const currentStory = stories[step];
    const userInput = e.value;

    // Compare user input to possible responses
    // Trigger matching response and set step to next key story index
}
```

Your message structure could be simplified further to better match the approach. For example turning the "bot messages" in an array of messages, adding the `options` key to the top level of the object and making the story an object, like so:

```js
const story = {
    messages: ['Hello!'],
    options: {
      "pizza": 2,
      "salads": 3 // Index of next story
    }
}
```

This way you can easily print out the messages by looping the `messages` array and select the picked option by using `currentStory.options[userInput]`.